# sh: mysql: command not found PHP exec() macOS

Tags: php, mysql, macos, exec, homebrew

I installed mysql with Homebrew on my MacOSX Sierra. Now when I try to execute the PHP function

```
<?= exec("mysql --version 2>&1"); ?>
```

i get the error: `sh: mysql: command not found`

PS: mysql is working fine from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probable that the path used by PHP does not include the location where the `mysql` binary was installed. Normally this is `/usr/local/bin` which is non-standard and not in the default path. Remember, altering your personal path doesn't impact the path of already running system services.

You can probably make this work by specifying the full path to the executable, that is the result of:

```
which mysql
```

Which is probably `/usr/local/bin/mysql`.

Comment: which mysql in exec returns nothing. What can i do now?

Comment: run `which mysql` in the terminal and change your exec command to use that path explicitly in the exec command.

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. Is there a way to use it without changing the source-code? I mean any change i can do in my configuration

Comment: If you can, add `/usr/local/bin` to a file like `/etc/paths.d/90-homebrew` and see if that picks up after a restart.